# Mouse Over Effect on Child Div --- Need Solution

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I need to remove mouse out effect on child div.

Just use that code as it is to understand the problem.

Here is my Code:

```
<div onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)" style="background-color:#D94A38;width:120px;height:20px;padding:40px;">Mouse Over Me</div>

<script>
function mOut(obj)
{
obj.innerHTML="Thank You"
}

function mOver(obj)
{
obj.innerHTML='<table style=" border:solid 1px #ff0000;"><tr><td><label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="64" value="SwapnilC" autocomplete="off"><br/><label for="pass">Password</label><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="Password"></div><div style=" float:right;width:90px;background-color:#933;" onClick="ClickLogin();">Login</div><div style="float:right; margin-right:10px; width:20px; padding-top:4px;"> <img id="PP_loading"  title="Processing Request" style="display:none;" src="images/ajaxProcess.gif" /> </td></tr></table>'
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't append html markup on mouseover, instead use classes to hide/show the table on mouse over/out

Javascript:

```
function mOut(obj)
{
    obj.style.display="none";
}

function mOver(obj)
{
    obj.style.display="block"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better put a span with "Tahnk you" and your table directly inside the div.
Then have table hidden ("display: none") and switch visibility when needed
span display: none|inline;
table display: none|block;

And all that can be done just using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

jQuery : .removeAttr( attributeName ) functionality.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Change title</button>
<input type="text" title="hello there" />
<div id="log"></div>

<script>
(function() {
  var inputTitle = $("input").attr("title");
  $("button").click(function () {
    var input = $(this).next();

    if ( input.attr("title") == inputTitle ) {
      input.removeAttr("title")
    } else {
      input.attr("title", inputTitle);
    }

    $("#log").html( "input title is now " + input.attr("title") );
  });
})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```